# MemoryMappedViewStream.ReadAsync() reading beyond the end of the memory mapped file

Tags: c#, async-await, memory-mapped-files

I am working on a sample to show how to read a large file and process it in chunks. It seems to be misbehaving however, returning an invalid number of bytes read.

For example, imagine we have a test file with a length of 8320 bytes and we use the following code to read it in chunks of 4096 bytes:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> ConvertInChunks(string filePath, int chunkSize,
[EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    byte[]? buffer = null;
    try
    {
        buffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(chunkSize);
        var memory = buffer.AsMemory(0, chunkSize);

        var fileLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
        using var mm = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath);
        await using var accessor = mm.CreateViewStream();

        var bytesRead = 0L;
        while (bytesRead < fileLength)
        {
            var read = await accessor.ReadAsync(memory, cancellationToken);
            bytesRead += read;

            yield return memory[..read].ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (buffer is not null)
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
    }
}
```

What I am finding is that the final iteration is still returning a `read` value of 4096. This seems like a bug to me, but maybe I am doing something incorrectly in my setup. I can work around this by explicitly splitting my memory buffer so that it is the minimum between bytes remaining and 4096, but I really expected the call to ReadAsync to read either 4096 or less when there is less data remaining in the stream. Note, I also tried the other `ReadAsync` overload with a buffer and explicit offset and count and it had the same behavior.

Comment: to quote from the docs of the `CreateViewStream` API: "the size of the view might be larger than the size of the source file on disk. This is because views are provided in units of system pages, and the size of the view is rounded up to the next system page size." - try specifying the length explicitly when calling `CreateViewStream`

Comment: @MarcGravell - thank you and thanks for pointing to those docs. I was looking at the memory mapped file docs and then the source code for UnmanagedStream...but skipped over the CreateViewStream docs ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @MarkGravell for this answer:

The solution is simple, set the view stream size explicitly in the create call:

```
var fileLength = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
using var mm = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filePath);
await using var accessor = mm.CreateViewStream(0, fileLength);
```